# How to get all special characters to work in Typing of the Dead?

Tags: virtualization, the-typing-of-the-dead

I've bought TotD and installed in on Windows 10, running as a virtual machine (Parallels Desktop) on my MacBook Air.

I can get the game to run in Windows 95 compatibility mode and most keys work fine. But a few keys simply don't work, including `'`, ```, and `=`. And I've found that to type `[` I need to type `]`, to type `]` I need to type `\` (i.e., the keys just right of the intended characters).

Is there anything I should do to make all special characters work when playing TotD on Windows in a virtual machine?

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this is relevant, but I've found someone having the exact same problem with DosBox:

https://sourceforge.net/p/dosbox/bugs/384/

None of the suggestions on that page or in the referenced links worked for me though.

Comment: Did you try looking in the virtual machine's settings to see if anything is wrong with your keyboard?